# Can you use partial classes to make two (equivalent) codebehind pages in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, partial-classes

We are using T4 to generate our .aspx and .vb files. Everything works well - but we often have to customise behaviour on the pages.

However, we also occasionally have to regenerate pages - which has the potential to wipe out work which would otherwise still be valid.

I would like a setup like this:

```
Default.aspx 'which would contain the controls
Default.aspx.vb 'which would bind, load and save data
Default.behaviour.vb '(or something like that) - which would store the behaviour
```

With both the pages being able to reference the controls.

Is that at all possible?

Stevedog: Thanks for that, I suspect my mistake will be more obvious in code - here is an example:

```
'##in codebehind Default.asp.vb:
'##there is a asp:label called lblTest
Partial Class pages_Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            writeMessage()
        End If
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub writeMessage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

AND

```
'##in codefile Default.behaviour.vb:
Partial Public Class pages_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub writeMessage()
        lbltest.Text = "Hello"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is this a website or a web application?  Is it actually possible to declare two code-behind files?  What are the merits of doing that?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones basically the T4 generates all the generic parts of our sites, the bind, load and saves - but behaviour is often really page specific - so we add that to the codebehind. We sometimes need to regenerate the T4 - potentially wiping the customisations - during periods of rapid prototyping. It would be nice if it was isolated and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make as many partial classes as you want for the same class, and the example you give is exactly their main purpose.  The code in the partial class can access everything in the rest of the class as if it was all in the same class declaration in the same file.  I'm not really familiar with ASP or T4, but I can't imagine why any of that would change the way partial classes work.

Comment: I am really glad to hear that. Would you mind taking a look at the code above and show me the error of my ways?

Comment: in the behaviour.vb page it tends to complain that the label is not declared. I tried creating Protected/Dim lblTest As Label.. I am scrabbling for ideas. If I make the Sub partial, it complains 'partial methods must have empty method bodies'.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't know.  Maybe it is an issue with ASP.  That's certainly allowed in other kinds of projects.  Like I said, I don't know much about ASP, unfortunately.  I found this link: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071509-1.aspx  But it only talks about ASP in the sense that it uses partial classes, not in the sense of adding your own.

Comment: I had seen that very article - and I can't seem to tweak it to work with two files. I wouldn't mind if there was no IDE support, but it seems like it isn't supported with this paradigm. Unless someone can help me. Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: Just an update, I seem to be able to make partial classes work on certain types of projects, critically I do web development so these are the two types of app I use: http://maordavid.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/aspnet-20-web-site-vs-web-application.html and it seems to work on 'sites' but not 'applications'

Comment: That's odd.  I'd expect it to be the exact opposite because at least with an 'application', you have a project file where you can explicitly include all the partial class files for the class and precompile it.  With a 'site' you are relying on it to auto-detect it so it can compile it on-demand.